# Should I put my /var on an SSD partition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I know that people asked about it - whether to put your /var partition on SSD? Why and why not? Many people said that it's not good idea to put it to SSD cause it wears off the SSD and can harm your drive. Here are decent tests to show you that it's not harmful for SSD to put there your /var partition. Have a look:
[Introducing the SSD Endurace Experiment](http://techreport.com/review/24841/introducing-the-ssd-endurance-experiment)
[The SSD Endurance Experiment: They're all dead](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead)
What do you think about it?
I ask because I'm about to put /var on SSD before installing Linux and would like to have some fresh view on it.

Comment: Answers to this question will be highly opinion-based, and therefore this question does not fit into the good Q/A style that exists on this site.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it. It was the first place that came to my mind to ask about this thing. If it violates anything feel free to close/delete it. I already know my response.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just asking for personally opinions, I would say, don't care about wearing off issues. You buy SSDs for daily usage and for experience improvement, not as part of your personal collection. Things always degrade gradually.

Actually, for most Windows and Mac OS X SSD users, in most of the cases their entire system runs on the SSD, including logging and whatever else, sometimes even swap files.

However if you have **some other application** that really requires high-frequency r/w operations, you may think of using RAM disks with loading on start-up and backup upon shutdown. I am not sure if this works for `/var` though...

Answer (score 2):

In short, here's the basic ruleset for determining whether or not to put a partition on your SSD:

[image]

So basically, always put it on your SSD if you need high speed, or if you have space for it.  The more on the SSD the better.  Modern SSDs will take a beating before they die, and they will let you know if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To give you an insight, I´ve been using an SSD on my Macbook Pro for everything the last 3years. Until 3 weeks ago i did not even have a linuxbox. That means all downloads / converting was happening on my Macbook. 
On top of that i work on it 3-8 hours a day.

Stil going strong with out errors...

EDIT:

I use an 128GB SSD for my entire linux system and a 2TB for /media (Old habit of putting Movies/Series in /media.

Select your /media mount point for your HDD during install

I also move my download folder to /media (or the HDD)

```
sudo mkdir /media/Downloads
sudo chmod 755 /media/Downloads
sudo chown root:adm /media/Downloads
#This next command deletes your Downloads, be sure to move content.
rm -fr Downloads
ln -s /media/Downloads
```